# Invoice calculation tool is rounding number on total from deposit field

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I cannot see why I need to fix this bug. On the Fiddle below you will see an invoice form. If you enter a price on the invoice item like 12.55 for example, you will then see it calculate everything in the bottom right. Now if you enter the deposit value 1.25 it just rounds the total off to .00 and not including the pennies.

Anyone have any ideas? The code I have written to do the deposit is:

```
$(document).on('input', '.calculate.deposit', function () {
        // calculate deposit
        var calcDeposit = parseInt($('#invoice_total').val()) - parseInt($('#invoice_deposit').val());
        $('.invoice-total').text((calcDeposit).toFixed(2));
        $('#invoice_total').val((calcDeposit).toFixed(2));
    });
```

When you use the shipping with pennies it seems to work fine it's just the deposit rounding it all off. All of the JS is added to the fiddle.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qmtgbwqv/

Comment: Maybe by adding it to the calculate function might resolve this? but not sure best way on that so if someone thinks that's better and can help me on that would be perfect!

Comment: You're throwing away the cents with `parseInt`. integers dont have decimal places.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qmtgbwqv/1/ yup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `parseFloat` instead of `parseInt`

Answer (score 3):

Change your `parseInt()` to `parseFloat()`.

Your code:

```
$(document).on('input', '.calculate.deposit', function () {
    // calculate deposit
    var calcDeposit = parseInt($('#invoice_total').val()) - parseInt($('#invoice_deposit').val());
    $('.invoice-total').text((calcDeposit).toFixed(2));
    $('#invoice_total').val((calcDeposit).toFixed(2));
});
```

Becomes

```
$(document).on('input', '.calculate.deposit', function () {
    // calculate deposit
    var calcDeposit = parseFloat($('#invoice_total').val()) - parseFloat($('#invoice_deposit').val());
    $('.invoice-total').text((calcDeposit).toFixed(2));
    $('#invoice_total').val((calcDeposit).toFixed(2));
});
```

Comment: Its not round off now which is great! however if it is 120.55 and i use deposit 20.55 it just takes off the 20 and not pennies... any ideas? and thanks for your help.

Comment: Ahh ignore that, noticed your update! Thanks for you help all working :)

Comment: Yes I forgot to edit one of the `parseInt()` to `parseFloat()`. You're welcome!